# jquery datatable with mvc project not working

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

i am trying to generate table using Jquery.Datatable , the table generated but without rendering the data , When the developer tools are opened the regular error appear although the jquery & datatable references added to the page in order , 
so any help here

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


 <table id="datatableId" data-url="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>


<script>
    var datatable = {
        table: null,
        initializedDataTable: function () {
            var $tablea = $(".table-striped");
            datatable.table = $tablea.DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                "alengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
                ajax: {
                    url: $tablea.prop("data-url"),
                    type: "POST"
                },
                "columns": [{ "data": "FirstName" },
                { "data": "LasttName" },
                { "data": "Gender" }],

                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            var inner = '<div class="btn-group">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdwon-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' +
                                'Actions' +
                                '</button>' +
                                '<div class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                '<a href="#"  class="drop-down-item btn btn-default edit" data-id="' + row.id + '" >Edit</a>' +
                                '<a href="#"  class="drop-down-item btn btn-default delete" data-id="' + row.id + '" >delete</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>';

                            return inner;
                        },
                        "targets": -1

                    }
                ],
                "pagingType": "full_numbers"

            });
            datatable.table.on('draw', function () {
                $('button[data-type="delete"]').click(function () {
                    var $button = $(this);

                });
                $('button[data-type="Edit"').click(function () {

                });
            });


        },
        getData: function () {
            if (datatable.table == null) {
                datatable.initializedDataTable();

            } else {
                datatable.table.ajax.reload();
            }
        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        datatable.getData();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: could you please post the error which u got in console

Comment: sure  , thank you for reply , 


Uncaught TypeError: $tablea.DataTable is not a function

    at Object.initializedDataTable (Index:78)


    at Object.getData (Index:126)


    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:136)


    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)


    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)


    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:447)


    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:118)

Comment: check in your console that you are not getting 404 error for DataTable js or try to click on datatable script to open it in new tab. It seems that there is some issue in file reference.

Comment: yes there are no 404 and when i clicked on the file it opened also the network section with no errors

Comment: use this cdn link instead of local  https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that path of your file should be

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Also try to replace your local reference with below code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
```

Because the version of jQuery you are using is very old.